# Google Analytics with Cocos2d

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, google-analytics

I'm trying to implement Google Analytics on my game with cocos2d. But how can I do it. because I am trying to allocate GAItrackedViewController manually. and I can't

```
  GAITrackedViewController *track = [[GAITrackedViewController alloc] init];

track.tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXX-X"];;
track.screenName = @"Menu";
```

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create an instance of `GAITrackedViewController` (and is recommended to don't create).

The `[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId]` will create an tracker or get an already initialized tracker.

So, the correct way is:

```
id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-X"];;
[tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Menu"];
```

PS 1: You can set the Tracking id on your AppDelegate, and then use `[[GAI sharedInstance] defaultTracker]` later. The tracker instance is persisted in the library.

PS 2: In cocos2d, you can't use `GAITrackedViewController`, because it only have the Director's View Controller. You need to use it manually with `GAITracker`.

Comment: HI @Bivis, I just test it and I can't see it on real time. id<GAITracker> tracker = [[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:@"UA-XXXX-X"];
    [tracker set:kGAIScreenName value:@"Menu"];

Comment: Hi, there's a problem when compiling, or crashes when running the app? Did you import GAITracker.h?

Comment: No I fix that, its working but I am using libGoogleAnalyticsServices.a no Debug

Comment: I forgot. This line.
    [tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] build]];

Comment: its now [GAIDictionaryBuilder createScreenView] according to their Comments/Documentation inside the code.

[GAIDictionaryBuilder createAppView] is deprecated.